# Kivy app using socket module crashed when building by buildozer

Tags: android, python-3.x, bluetooth, kivy, buildozer

I have an issue that I can't explain why it happened because I try to debug this for hours. 
My application runs succeed so it is nothing about import Python library. But it always crash when i press a button to send message through bluetooth using python socket. (App written using kivy framework and using buildozer to build apk file)

```
import socket

def callback(self,instance,pos): # function called when button click to send text typed in text input box 
    a = self.text   # it is text that in text input box
    macadd = '20:15:ff:7e:bc:9a'
    port = 1
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)   # this line cause the crash
```

Then I type command:

```
buildozer init
buildozer -v android debug
```

file buildozer.spec doesn't change. Everything is ok and I install in my Android 4.0 using API 21. Here is the problem: WHEN I COMMENT

```
#s = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
```

My app run and when click the button to submit, nothing happend, it's ok as function does.
BUT WHEN I REMOVE COMMENT:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
```

My app run and when click the button to submit, it's crashed. I don't know what to do now. I really need somebody can help me with this situation. So thank you.